# Dictionary Creation from DataFrame, Pandas, Python

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I want to create a dictionary where the key is a state name and the value is the sum of all the count corresponding to the state.

Example from dataFrame

```
State         Count
California    100
Colorado      100
California    54
Colorado      9254
```

I was trying to use the following, but not sure how to include a sum function inside this, also not sure if I should be using a zip method here:

```
df_dict = dict(zip(df.State, df.Count))
print df_dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the sum by group in the dataframe and then select the `'Count'` column and use `to_dict()` to convert the resulting Series to dictionary:

```
df_dict = df.groupby('State').agg('sum')['Count'].to_dict()
print df_dict
```

---

If you have more columns in the df than those two you probably want to do

```
df[['State','Count']].groupby('State').agg('sum')['Count'].to_dict()
```

to avoid calculating the sum for all of the columns.

Edit:

as EdChum suggested `.agg('sum')` can be shortened to `.sum()` which gives you the same result.

Comment: perfect, not sure if the ['Count'] is needed. unless i am missing something? @Pekka

Comment: It is needed to select the first (in this case only) column from the resulting DataFrame. Try it without it. You will get a nested dictionary. In that case your desired result is in the `Count` key.

Comment: So when we use the `['Count']` selection we get Series instead of DataFrame. Then we convert the Series (not DataFrame) to dictionary. Note that also DataFrames can be converted to dictionary with `to_dict()` but the result is different (nested dict).
See:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html
and
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Comment: I think the `agg` is unnecessary here

Answer (score 1):

That won't work properly, since the `dict` constructor will replace the value of each `state` as it goes, rather than summing. It's not a one-liner, but:

```
from collections import Counter

df_dict = Counter()
for state, count in zip(df.State, df.Count):
    df_dict[state] += count
```

will get you the total counts, and the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class has some extra functionality that may be useful for dictionaries of counts.